# Change the error message of a radio button

Tags: php, frameworks, zend-framework2, validation

I want to change the error message text of a radio button group, if no button was checked.
Currently i am trying it like this:

```
    $this->add(
        array(
            'name' => 'target_code',
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                    'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'My Custom Error Message.'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
```

This doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem as you! But in my case is an Select Element.

Comment: Yes, since yesterday i have the same Problem with a select element too.

Answer (score 2):

I had used this and it worked for me.

**Option-1:** change error message

Form:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Radio',
    'name' => 'gender',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Select your gender',
        'value_options' => array(
            1 => 'Male',
            2 => 'Female',
        ),
    )
));
```

Form Filter:

```
$this->inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'gender',
            'required' => true,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'InArray',
                    'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                    'options' => array(
                        'haystack' => array(1, 2),
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\InArray::NOT_IN_ARRAY => 'Please select your gender!'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                    'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                    'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Please select your gender!',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
)));
```

View error:

```
foreach ($form->get('gender')->getMessages() as $message) {
    echo $message;
    break;
}
```

Problem:

```
'break_chain_on_failure' => true
```

"break_chain_on_failure" is not working for me, so I have showing the first error message :)

**Option-2**: set one as checked always

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Radio',
    'name' => 'gender',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Select your gender',
        'value_options' => array(
            1 => 'Male',
            2 => 'Female',
        ),
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'value' => '1' //set checked to '1'
    )
));
```

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/zf2-custom-messages-in-input-filter-td4655498.html) may be useful. I don't understand the reasons, but it says, "You have to set required to false and allow_empty to true in order to set a custom message on a NotEmpty validator."